# Why can't I register HTC one ver 9 containing Android ver 6 OS to install ubertester

Tags: android, ubertesters

I went to http://beta.ubertesters.com/ and created an account.  I tried to register my android phone:
 - Model HTC One M9
 - With Android version 6 installed

I cannot register a phone with Android ver 6 on ubertester.  Has anyone had this problem before? Or has anyone got around this problem?

Thanks
Conor

Answer (score 0):

Ubertesters allows to connect Model HTC One M9, so there should not be any issues with it. May I ask you to send us more details at support@ubertesters.com so we can investigate the issue with your device?

Thank you.